# Titanium: Switch between windows created by different controllers

Tags: ios, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

In Titanium I have three controllers/views: A, B and C

I have a button bar at the bottom of the screen labelled [A], [B], and [C]

I want each button to cause the associated view to be shown. If the associated controller has not been run yet then the button runs code like: Alloy.createController("A"). So far so good.

However, if the controller has already been run and opened it's associated view I want the [A] button to just cause the previously generated view to be reshown and NOT cause the code in the associated controller to be run (because I want the user to see the old data in the view, not show new data).

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

just keep an initialized flag in the controller and check that the window has already been initialized.

that is my best advice without actually seeing any code.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. What I meant with my question is how can I show the last view associated with a controller that has already been created. I have a flag that tells me whether or not the controller has been created. If it has I want to do something like $.A.show(), but I don't seem to be able to access $.A from the B controller (for example).